# print the names which are in both files

Tags: sed, awk

I have two files. I would like to print the names which are in both files.

```
file1   

  1dfg   
  4rte
  aabd 
  hjgf

file2

  4rte
  2fgh
  1dfg
```

desired output

```
1dfg
4rte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` can do that:

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

Results:

```
1dfg   
4rte
```

---

However, `awk` may be more appropriate depending on the significance of whitespace:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0]; next } $0 in a' file2 file1
```

or:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } $1 in a' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
$ comm  -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
1dfg
4rte
```

Comment: If you don't need the files sorted, why sort them?

Comment: because comm command works only on sorted files.

Comment: :-) I know that. So, if the data is not required to be sorted *as part of the task*, why would you want to sort it just to be able to use "comm"?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cat file1 | grep -Fxf file2
```

and if you want it printed without grep search highlighting

```
cat file1 | grep -Fxf file2 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way using awk

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]+=1;next} a[$1]' file1.txt file2.txt`